# Jmeter multiple file uploads

Tags: file, select, jmeter

A simple question, I hope.

JMeter version: 3.0

How to include several files for upload at once, instead of selecting on a per file basis? I want to upload around 1000 files in a single request, and it will take forever to set up with the current user interface it seems.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [Beanshell PreProcessor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#BeanShell_PreProcessor) to dynamically build HTTP Request sampler payload providing source folder like:

1. Add Beanshell PreProcessor as a child of the [HTTP Request](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) sampler
2. Put the following code into the Beanshell PreProcessor's "Script" area

   ```
   import org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.util.HTTPFileArg;

   File folder = new File("path_to_your_folder");

   File[] files = folder.listFiles(new FileFilter() {
       public boolean accept(File file) {
           return file.isFile();
       }
   });
   if (files != null) {
       HTTPFileArg[] filesToUpload = new HTTPFileArg[files.length];

       for (int i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
           HTTPFileArg fileToUpload = new HTTPFileArg(files[i].getPath(), "your_param", "your_mime_type");
           filesToUpload[i] = fileToUpload;
       }
       sampler.setHTTPFiles(filesToUpload);
   }
   ```

Change the the following strings in the above script to match your environment:

- `path_to_your_folder` - full or relative path to folder where your files live
- `your_param` - to upload form `name` attribute`
- `your_mime_type` - to [MIME type](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Media_type) of the files

References:

- `sampler` - is shorthand for the [HTTPSamplerProxy](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/protocol/http/sampler/HTTPSamplerProxy.html)
- [HTTPFileArg](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/protocol/http/util/HTTPFileArg.html)
- [How to Use BeanShell: JMeter's Favorite Built-in Component](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/queen-jmeters-built-componentshow-use-beanshell)