# Jmeter multiple file uploads with file upload configuration and csv data set

Tags: shell, jmeter

I have *multiple* files which I'd like to upload at once. 
The files are in a directory, but it seems the 'File Upload' of the HTTP 
Request 
config element only allows me to select 1 file at a time.

I've configured a CSV Data Set Config element with one more file confiugured vairable, hoping that it would 
upload two files at once, but instead this it works for only one file configuration.

Only a single file is uploaded with each request.

So, the question: How to select all files  without creating different thread group?  Please look into images attached on link

[image: CSV Data Config with multiple file upload variables],

[image: File upload Configuration in http request sampler],

[image: csv file details]

Comment: I have tried  solution available on link but Bean shell pre processer not uploading multiple files:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39766994/jmeter-multiple-file-uploads

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It might be the case your application doesn't support multiple file uploads, i.e. **you can only upload one file at a time with 1 user**.

Try recording your file upload request using JMeter's [HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP(S)_Test_Script_Recorder) and see how do(es) generated [HTTP Request](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) sampler(s) look(s) like. Prior to recording make sure to copy the files you will be uploading into "bin" folder of your JMeter installation - only this way JMeter will be able to build correct requests, see [Recording File Uploads with JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/recording-file-uploads-jmeter) article for more details.

1. If you have 1 sampler with multiple files in the "Files Upload" tab - you will need to go for the solution from the referenced link
2. If you have 1 HTTP Request per file - you will not be able to use single one, in this case you can achieve simultaneous file upload via [Synchronizing Timer](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Synchronizing_Timer)

Comment: Application supports multiple file upload no doubt. I am unable to read/upload multiple files against same http request, that is the issue. I tried with bean shell pre processor but unable to do mapping of http request sampler parameters with bean shell script.

Comment: Please suggest inputs to get upload multiple file through same/single Http Request sampler.